# DDT for boolean functions must contain only powers of two

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, algorithm-design, s-boxes, arx

I see in many discussion on differential cryptanalysis of SBOX (and others boolean functions, see SIMON-like round functions, SPECK-like round function) the idea of reasoning in terms of *weights* associated with differentials. *Weight* is defined as minus the logarithm of the probability of a transition. Some seem to imply weight is always a integer number, others seem to care noting this is not the case in general. I agree with the latter, for the weight to be an integer one must obtain only powers of two in the Difference Distribution Table (DDT) of a boolean function. Maybe Am I missing a theorem that pose constraints on reasonable costruction for SBOXes that make DDT be only filled with powers of two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly possible for the Difference Distribution Table (DDT) to have entries that are not powers of $2.$ There is no "reasonable" criterion that would rule this out that I am aware of.

The entries do have to be even though by the simple argument that if the following nontrivial (i.e., $a\neq 0$) $(a,b)$ input output difference
$$
S(x\oplus a)\oplus S(x)=b
$$
occurs for $x=x_0,$ then it also occurs for $x=x_0\oplus a.$ So differences occur in pairs.

For example, the Sbox in the Heys tutorial [available here](http://www.cs.bc.edu/%7Estraubin/crypto2017/heys.pdf) has at least one entry equal to $6.$

[image]

Comment: DDT was cryptic...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now If we take the transition 0xC --> 0xD in Table 7 we have a weight with non zero decimal digits. Right?

Comment: Yes, since it's not a power of 2.